# How can we get all of the user's input data in a table using scilab?

Tags: input, scilab

I am trying to build a Binomial fitting program after calculating mean and variance. The program is executed properly, but I am not able to get all of the user's input data in a tabular format. Right now, only the last data is being captured in a tabular format.

**How can we get all of the user's input data in a table using scilab?**

Code and Output :
[Scinotes code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEnDg.png)

[Console output of Scilab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfL60.png)

Comment: You may want to review the answers to a similar question: "How to take multiple input from user Scilab": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804334/how-to-take-multiple-input-from-user-scilab

Looks like someone is suggesting the x_matrix function!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use vectors/arrays/matrix and the functions already available from Scilab (example: the function `sum` returns the sum of the elements of a matrix...).

See this code as an example: you can store the values and then do operations.

```
clear

N = input('N: ')
xin = zeros(1, N) //creating an array (all elements are zero)
fin = zeros(1, N)

for i = 1:N
    xin(1, i) = input('xin: ') // assign the element at line 1 and column i
    fin(1, i) = input('fin: ')
end

fsum = sum(fin)
product = xin.*fin // The .* means an elementwise product
fsp = sum(product)

for j = 1:N
    mprintf('\n\t %.2f \t %.2f \t %.2f', xin(1, j), fin(1, j), product(1, j))
end
```